# with ajax i cant dispaly data i dont know what i missing

Tags: php, ajax

i want to display data with ajax but operation is performed and data is not displaying.
**here code of ajax**

```
function changeStatus(id){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'include/status.php',
            data:'status='+id,
            success:function(data){
                if(data=='1')
                {
                    $(this).html(data);
                }else{ alert("sorry"); }
            }
        });
    }
```

and php code is: 
this is a button.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnblk" onclick=" return changeStatus(<?php echo $data[0] ?>,this)">
```

Comment: `changeStatus()` only takes 1 argument, why are you calling it with 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

element as second argument of changeStatus function

```
function changeStatus(id,element){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'include/status.php',
            data:'status='+id,
            success:function(data){
                if(data=='1')
                {
                    $(element).html(data);
                }else{ alert("sorry"); }
            }
        });
    }
```

Pass first argument as string:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnblk" onclick=" return changeStatus('<?php echo $data[0] ?>',this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnblk" onclick="changeStatus(<?php echo $data[0] ?>)"></a>
```

Comment: I think the argument need to enclose with single quote if `$data[0]` is string.

Answer (score 0):

You need give single quotes if `$data[0]` coming as string,

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnblk" onclick=" return changeStatus('<?php echo $data[0]; ?>')">
```